# How do I find the Upper Range and Lower range of the color space in given coordinates?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, range, hsv

So I am working on a project in I specify 4 coordinates as a rectangular area and need to find what is the upper and lower color range in that area.
This is the test image:
[Test image in RGB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f03Xp.jpg)

And this is the rectangular area in which I need to predict the upper and lower range of color - (351, 467), (505, 467), (505, 538), (351, 538)

I thought converting the image to HSV would make it bit more accurate.

[HSV Image with coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSQ30.jpg)

Currently I am using this code

```py
def upper_range(x1, x2, y1, y2, hsv):
    for i in range(hsv[y1:y2,x1:x2,0].shape[0]):
        H_upper = np.amax(hsv[y1:y2,x1:x2,0][i])
    for i in range(hsv[y1:y2,x1:x2,0].shape[0]):
        S_upper = np.amax(hsv[y1:y2,x1:x2,1][i])
    for i in range(hsv[y1:y2,x1:x2,0].shape[0]):
        V_upper = np.amax(hsv[y1:y2,x1:x2,2][i])
    range_upper = np.array([int(H_upper), int(S_upper), int(V_upper)])
    return range_upper
def lower_range(x1, x2, y1, y2, hsv):
    for i in range(hsv[y1:y2,x1:x2,0].shape[0]):
        H_lower = np.amin(hsv[y1:y2,x1:x2,0][i])
    for i in range(hsv[y1:y2,x1:x2,0].shape[0]):
        S_lower = np.amin(hsv[y1:y2,x1:x2,1][i])
    for i in range(hsv[y1:y2,x1:x2,0].shape[0]):
        V_lower = np.amin(hsv[y1:y2,x1:x2,2][i])
    range_lower = np.array([int(H_lower),int(S_lower),int(V_lower)])
    return range_lower

image = cv2.imread('test_image.png')
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lowerrange = lower_range(351, 505, 467, 538, hsv)
uperrange = upper_range(351, 505, 467, 538, hsv)
```

But the upper and lower range that I am getting is not perfect, and I guess it makes sense why it's wrong because currently I am just getting the max and min value in every channel using np.amax and combining those channel value making a range array.

But it's not necessary that whatever the max and min array we get IS ACTUALLY AN EXISTING VALUE IN THE IMAGE AREA.

For example. if we consider four values [(220, 3 ,4), (180, 73, 29), (121, 120, 45), (2, 5,89)]

my code would output [(220, 120, 89)] as upper and [(2, 3, 4)] as lower range but that's not perfectly right.

Any suggestions how I can improve my code?

Comment: of the four colors you provided as example, which do you define to be the correct upper range of color? please provide your ideal output

Comment: @ZLi So, to make it simpler, https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/06/deep-learning-project-image-object-opencv/ I am using this blog to implement in my project with some changes majorly, I want to automate the process of providing the lower and upper range which they have provided manually

Comment: @ZLi Sorry, if I am not making it clear enough, I am new to machine learning and all. Hopefully the blog would make it clearer what I want

Comment: I feel that in the blog, the upper range is just the max of each hsv value, which is what your code is doing. You could load the blog's data to confirm.